# Executing SVN commands with Python script

Tags: python, python-2.7, svn

I want to execute the following SVN command using Python:

`svn log -v --xml --stop-on-copy --no-auth-cache --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username <user> --password <password> <repo>`

I've tried this way:

```
cmd = 'svn log -v --xml --stop-on-copy --no-auth-cache --trust-server-cert --non-interactive --username <user> --password <password> <repo>'
args = shlex.split(cmd)
pro = subprocess.Popen(
    args,
    shell=True,
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, err = pro.communicate()
```

If I execute the SVN, it returns a XML.
If I execute the Python, the output and err are blank.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried to build the args list yourself? `Popen` might play you with the order of the `shlex.split` as `log` could be needed as part of the main command (`svn log`) and not as an argument.

Comment: Also, `shlex.split()` isn't really necessary here, `cmd.split()` would be sufficient.

Comment: @RafaelAguilar, I've tried with no luck.

Comment: @LucasBeier what is the return value, `streams = pro.communicate()`, `ret_code = pro.returncode` try this and print the return value.